# Disabling and re-enabling an EditText field: Cursor and keyboard do not reappear after re-enabling it

Tags: java, android

I am setting up a log in activity, with username and password. I want to disable the user name and password edit text fields whilst the app is trying to log the user on to the system.

```
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {

    valueAnimator.start();

    loginView.setEnabled(false);
    loginView.setFocusable(false);
    loginView.clearFocus();
    passwordView.setEnabled(false);
    passwordView.setFocusable(false);
    passwordView.clearFocus();
```

I want to then re-enable/activate the edit text fields if the sign in fails or is unsuccessful. I've followed the instructions on a few similar questions, but whenever I try and allow the fields to be editable again, the cursor and keyboard don't appear again. I can long click on the fields, and the cursor will appear, but won't allow any editing or change, without exiting and going back into app.

```
                passwordView.clearFocus();
                loginView.clearFocus();

                loginView.setEnabled(true);
               // loginView.setFocusable(true);
                loginView.setClickable(true);
                loginView.isFocusableInTouchMode();

                passwordView.setEnabled(true);
                // passwordView.setFocusable(true);
                passwordView.setClickable(true);
                passwordView.isFocusableInTouchMode();

                loginView.setCursorVisible(true);
                passwordView.setCursorVisible(true);
                loginView.requestFocus();

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_login"
        android:focusable="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Currently using Android Studio 3.1.4, with

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "co.***.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
```

Comment: I think you should use setFocusableInTouchMode to true rather than use isFocusableInTouchMode which will return you the current value which is not used anywhere in the scope of your code provided to this site.

Comment: Brilliant! Did exactly what I wanted, I've spent far too long on this by now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setEnabled(false)` for disable the editText field and `setEnabled(true)`for enable the editText field.

If sign in fails or is unsuccessful you can again enable the edit text field, it depends on your response.

No need to use other attribute or method you can use only `setEnabled(false)`/`setEnabled(true)`.

Comment: No need to add attribute/tag in xml file you can implement this functionality programatically on onCreate method or when your response will come.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code when you press the singInButton:

```
 Button singInButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        singInButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            loginView.setEnabled(false);
            loginView.clearFocus();
            passwordView.setEnabled(false);
            passwordView.clearFocus();


         });
```

And you do this when the error happens:

```
public void onErrorLogin(){
            loginView.setEnabled(true);
            loginView.isFocusableInTouchMode();

            passwordView.setEnabled(true);
            passwordView.isFocusableInTouchMode();

            loginView.setCursorVisible(true);
            passwordView.setCursorVisible(true);
}
```

This should works.